# Android ListView with Ripple effect

Tags: android, android-listview, ripple, rippledrawable

I have a ListView and each row uses a custom background color. I'd like to ensure that the default highlight is shown when the user touches a row, so I've defined a drawable with a selector, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:drawable="@color/clear" android:state_selected="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@color/clear" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@color/clear" android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
        </selector>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

At first glance, it seems to work. **However, if I scroll to a row that wasn't previously on the screen, the first time I tap the row, I don't get a ripple.** But then if I tap it again, I do see the ripple. If I scroll the row off the screen and then back on again, same thing keeps happening.

Any ideas??

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post more code for us. it is not clear how you are settings this background, or what element you set it on.

Comment: I think it's because your masking the ripple effect over '@color/clear' which would be invisible.  Try a different color like blue and see if the effect is the same.

Comment: I've switched from using a ListView to using a RecyclerView and it all now seems to work.. I'm guessing it was just a bug in ListView.

Comment: Can you share any more code with how you implemented this on a recycler view? I'm currently trying to do the same thing - add a ripple effect to the recycler view items where each item has a different background color. 

Did you add the ripple drawable to the recycler view itself or to each item individually?

Comment: For each item in the recyclerview, just set the item's ViewGroup to android:focusable="true", android:clickable="true", and android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"